# In Selenium, how is it possible to retrieve, by code, the value of a "FindsBy" attribute?

Tags: selenium

For my tests, I have an all my WebElements declared like this :

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[contains(text(),'blah blah')], Priority = 0)]
private IWebElement _webElementName;
```

I would like to get the XPath value for using this value in an other function (because this function can take only one parameter : a By variable).

I tried with the "GetAttribute" method, but it's for the attribute of the element in the page and I need the "Using" value of the FindsBy attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In java this can be done using `final` but for c# you can try using `readonly` keyword.

```
readonly static string xpathString ="//div[contains(text(),'blah blah')]";

[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = xpathString, Priority = 0)]
private IWebElement _webElementName;   

// Now xpathString can be used anywhere
```

Comment: thank you. I don't think that it's the best solution but It's an alternative solution,

Comment: I tried your solution, but the compilation is failed : _An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'xpathString_

Comment: @yannick - The solution is correct but the thing is you need class object to refer it.